# How to parse a heterogeneous list of lists without a pre-tag?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

*How should I modify this boost::spirit code to parse for any combination of ranges or lists?*

Note that this question is somewhat different from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591660/how-to-generalize-a-spirit-parser-to-take-lists-in-arbitrary-order).  In this case, I don't have a special pre-tag like `RANGE:` and `LIST:` that helps me parse, so I'm not sure if we require some kind of look-ahead here.

*I do need to keep the parses separate, though, as doing so will help me capture the results into different data structures.*

**objective**  get all four test-cases to pass

**EDIT ANSWER that seems to work with more complicated expressions**

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::vector<boost::tuple<std::string,std::vector<int>>>   MY_TYPE;

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct my_grammar :
qi::grammar<Iterator, MY_TYPE(), Skipper>
{
    my_grammar() :
        my_grammar::base_type( entries )
    {
        entries %=
            *(
                +(qi::char_ - '-')
                >> qi::lit( "->" )
                >> ( comma | range )
            )
            ;

        range %= '{' >> qi::int_ >> ':' >> qi::int_ >> ':' >> qi::int_ >> '}';
        comma %= '{' >> (qi::int_ % ',') >> '}';

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE( range   );
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE( comma   );
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE( entries );
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>(), Skipper> 
        range, comma;

    qi::rule<Iterator, MY_TYPE(), Skipper> 
        entries;
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void TryParse( const std::string& input, const std::string& label )
{
    MY_TYPE entries;
    auto it(input.cbegin()), end( input.cend() );
    my_grammar<decltype(it), qi::space_type> entry_grammar;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(it, end, entry_grammar, qi::space, entries)
            && it == end)
    {
        std::cerr << label << " SUCCESS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << label << " FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::string range_first = "foo -> {1:9:1}\nbar -> {1,2,3,4,5}\n";
    std::string comma_first = "foo -> {1,2,3,4,5}\nbar -> {1:9:1}\n";
    std::string comma_only  = "foo -> {1,2,3,4,5}\n";
    std::string range_only  = "foo -> {1:9:1}\n";

    TryParse( range_first, "RANGE FIRST" );
    TryParse( comma_first, "COMMA FIRST" );
    TryParse( range_only,  "RANGE ONLY"  );
    TryParse( comma_only,  "COMMA ONLY"  );
}
```

**EDIT NEW OUTPUT (STILL CAN'T HANDLE HETEROGENEOUS LIST)**

```
/tmp$ g++ -g -std=c++11 sandbox.cpp -o sandbox && ./sandbox 
COMMA FIRST FAIL
RANGE FIRST FAIL
COMMA ONLY SUCCESS
RANGE ONLY SUCCESS
/tmp$
```

**EDIT IMPROVED CODE (STILL CAN'T HANDLE HETEROGENEOUS LIST)**

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct my_grammar :
qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<int>(), Skipper>
{
    my_grammar() :
        my_grammar::base_type(entries)
    {
        entries %= 
            *('{' >> qi::int_
            >> ( range_tail | comma_tail ))
        ;

        range_tail %= ':' >> qi::int_ >> ':' >> qi::int_ >> '}';
        comma_tail %= *( ',' >> qi::int_ ) >> '}';

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(entries   );
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(comma_tail);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(range_tail);
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>(), Skipper> entries, comma_tail, range_tail;
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void TryParse( const std::string& input, const std::string& label )
{
    std::vector<int> entries;
    auto it(input.cbegin()), end( input.cend() );
    my_grammar<decltype(it), qi::blank_type> entry_grammar;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(it, end, entry_grammar, qi::blank, entries)
            && it == end)
    {
        std::cerr << label << " SUCCESS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << label << " FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::string range_first = "{3:5:7}\n{1,2,3,4,5}";
    std::string comma_first = "{1,2,3,4,5}\n{3:5:7}";
    std::string comma_only  = "{1,2,3,4,5}";
    std::string range_only  = "{3:5:7}";

    TryParse( comma_first, "COMMA FIRST" );
    TryParse( range_first, "RANGE FIRST" );
    TryParse( comma_only,  "COMMA ONLY"  );
    TryParse( range_only,  "RANGE ONLY"  );
}
```

**ORIGINAL CODE**

**compile and run**

```
/tmp$ g++ -g -std=c++11 sandbox.cpp -o sandbox && ./sandbox 
COMMA FIRST FAIL
RANGE FIRST FAIL
COMMA ONLY SUCCESS
RANGE ONLY FAIL
/tmp$
```

**sandbox.cpp**

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>


namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
typedef int Entry;

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct my_grammar :
qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<Entry>(), Skipper>
{
    my_grammar() :
        my_grammar::base_type(entries)
    {
        entries %= 
            *( 
                '{' >>
                    ( comma_list | range_list )
                >> '}'
            )
        ;

        comma_list %= qi::int_ % ',';
        range_list %= qi::int_ >> ':' >> qi::int_ >> ':' >> qi::int_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(entries);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(comma_list);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(range_list);
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Entry>(), Skipper> entries, comma_list, range_list;
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void TryParse( const std::string& input, const std::string& label )
{
    std::vector<Entry> entries;
    auto it(input.cbegin()), end( input.cend() );
    my_grammar<decltype(it), qi::blank_type> entry_grammar;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(it, end, entry_grammar, qi::blank, entries)
            && it == end)
    {
        std::cerr << label << " SUCCESS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << label << " FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::string range_first = "{3:5:7}\n{1,2,3,4,5}";
    std::string comma_first = "{1,2,3,4,5}\n{3:5:7}";
    std::string comma_only  = "{1,2,3,4,5}";
    std::string range_only  = "{3:5:7}";

    TryParse( range_first, "COMMA FIRST" );
    TryParse( comma_first, "RANGE FIRST" );
    TryParse( comma_only,  "COMMA ONLY"  );
    TryParse( range_only,  "RANGE ONLY"  );
}
```

Comment: `blank` doesn't skip over `\n` only spaces or tabs([Documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char_class.html)). `space` does skip returns and new lines.

Comment: +1 @llonesmiz - ty - you're right - changing all to `space` fixes it... ...unfortunately, this snippet is not a good example of my real problem.  I have a parse where that `comma_list` or `range_list` is deep inside a statement parse (the rhs).  Somehow, this example doesn't work in the real code... ...looking into it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consume the leading number in common code.  After that number have either a range tail or a list tail.  List tails start with a , and range tails start with a :.

Possibly fold the } into the tail, so a list tail is (,number)*} and a range tail is :number:number}, which makes the empty list easier to parse.

Comment: +1 for a good answer - I have edited the OP to use tail-recursion so we can now handle either a `range_tail` or a `comma_tail` but still trying to get any mix of the two to work.

Comment: So it now handles one list or the other.  And if you follow the advice above and skip newlines it handles one list then the other?

Comment: Actually, the skipping the new lines was probably the main cause.  Once I fixed the second chunk of code in the OP with `space` instead of `blank` it worked for a mix of lists and ranges.  However, I will accept your answer as it makes clear in the code a problem with this grammar: I cannot tell if I have a range-type or a comma-type until I have parsed beyond that first item.